# Smart gwt listgrid date type field is sending null value

Tags: java, date, gwt, listgrid

I have a smart gwt listgrid with a date of birth field of type date.While performing add or update ,it is throwing null pointer exception.when I used fire bug to check whether all values are properly sent to server side,I saw dob value is "--".So I used dateformatter to format the date but still the date value is "--".I don't know why after entering the date value on listgrid still it is sending null value to server side.

Comment: You should provide us with `code` samples from the problematic area in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: What version of SmartGWT are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem but it is fixed automatically in latest version of **SmartClient**.

Currently I am using SmartClient `version v9.0p_2013-09-22/PowerEdition Deployment` (built 2013-09-22).

Please upgrade it if you are using a version below this.